# Mysql query to retrieve record using between for two dates

Tags: mysql, between

I have one requirement and i am totally confused how to write the query. I am a fresher in this company so please help me

User will select the following Dates:

Ex:
fromDate: `2013-08-02` toDate: `2013-09-03` (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
id  resort_id   room_id Date1       Date2       price
5   35      45          2013-11-01  2013-11-30  3000.00
6   35      50          2013-07-25  2013-08-25  2000.00
7   35      541         2013-07-25  2013-08-25  4000.00
8   35      541         2013-08-26  2013-09-26  4000.00
```

Now i should get price based result for each date or sum of the price for both the date group by room id

Expected result

```
id  resort_id   room_id     Date1       Date2       price
6   35      50              2013-07-25  2013-08-25  2000.00
7   35      541             2013-07-25  2013-08-25  4000.00
8   35      541             2013-08-26  2013-09-26  4000.00
```

OR

```
id  resort_id      room_id  price
6   35             50       2000.00
7   35             541      8000.00
```

Comment: can you pls explain what is Date1 and Date2?

Comment: this IS a complicated query

Comment: @bew I think those are the date ranges for that price

Comment: Date1 and Date 2 similar to from_date and to_date. price should be shown in the result if the user provided date between date1 and date2

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee yes you are correct

Comment: first of all you need to store those dates as the mysql date type column. Otherwise this query will be pretty hard to pull off. So convert those

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee ok i will convert into `DATE` Type, can you consider this as a `DATE` type and provide me the query?

Comment: I'll habe to build the query.This is not a simple query, actually. The sort that DBAs are actually hired to do,  to be honest. So I need data to test it on

Comment: also the first rowhas invalid data 16 is not a month.

Comment: mysql date is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd. i need that format

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee I have changed the dateformat here as well as in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE "2013-08-02" between Date1 AND Date2 UNION 
SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE "2013-09-03" BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2
```

Its a single query. Spread it on two lines for easier readability. I am pretty sure this query is missing something. I'll need a larger test set to verify. This won't select the middle cases.
Change the first date with your user's selected dates.

Comment: @SomeshMukerjee This query works fine and i am getting first expected result.

Comment: Myself written one query and i am getting 2nd expected result.

    `SELECT resort_id, room_id, SUM( test_price.price ) 
    FROM test_price
    WHERE  '2013-08-02'
    BETWEEN from_date
    AND to_date
    OR  '2013-09-03'
    BETWEEN from_date
    AND to_date
    GROUP BY room_id`

Comment: careful though this might not work if the date falls between january 2013 and October 2013. It won't select the rooms in between, but you should be able to build from here

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM lr_price_peak_rates  WHERE  `from_date`>='2014-04-08' AND `to_date`<='2014-04-30'
```

try the above query it can be working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT
  id,
  resort_id,
  room_id,
  Date1,
  Date2,
  SUM(price) AS Total_Price
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE Date1> '2013-02-08' AND Date2 < '2013-02-09'
```

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Thank you for your comment. Crescent Can you provide me interval based select query?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee i have provided yyyy-mm-dd format. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

hey try this (sql server )

> SELECT  room_id,SUM(price) FROM @table WHERE date1>='07/25/2013' AND date2<='09/26/2013' GROUP BY room_id

Comment: This is working fine with your given date. But user may select any date range.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where date1 > '08/02/2013' AND date2 < '09/02/2013' ORDER BY date1 ASC, price ASC
```

Comment: user dates should be between date1 and date2. for ex: date: 08/02/2013 is applicable with rowid: 6 and 7, date: 09/02/2013 is applicable with row id 8. Using your query i am getting 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE date between Date1 AND Date2 UNION 
SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE date BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2